# Join on different types

Tags: postgresql, join, datatypes

In a database I have two tables:

1. The first has a field named `taxonomy_id` that is an `integer`
2. The latter has a field named `ID` that is a `character varying`

The two tables are related: if it exists a row in the first one with `taxonomy_id = N` it will exist a row in the second one with `ID = N.toString`.

Now, I would like to do the join between this two tables; naturally the "normal" join doesn't work because of the type mismatch.

Can you help me solving this?

I'm using `PostgreSQL`.

Comment: Why is ID a string?

Comment: I'm querying a DataWarehouse, it seems that during the creation phase this kind of queries hadn't been taken into account :(

Answer (score 13):

#### Not valid integer types

If the values in the field are **not** actually **valid `integer` types** (digits and leading `-` only), a `JOIN` like [@mustaccio suggested](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/42983/3684) would fail with an exception: you couldn't cast to `integer` at all.

It would have to be the other (even more expensive) way round:

```
SELECT *
FROM   tbl1 t1
JOIN   tbl2 t2 ON t1.taxonomy_id::varchar = t2.id;
```

Also, since @mustaccio misleadingly suggested to use `int8`: **Don't.** [`integer` equals `int4`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-numeric.html). `int8` would be `bigint`.

You can support that with a functional index:

```
CREATE INDEX tbl1_taxonomy_id_idx ON tbl1 (cast(taxonomy_id AS varchar));
```

#### Valid integer types

If we are dealing with valid `integer` types, you could just convert your column `id` to `integer` - if your setup allows that.

```
ALTER TABLE tbl2 ALTER COLUMN id TYPE integer USING id::int;
```

Then your problem is gone for good:

```
SELECT *
FROM   tbl1 t1
JOIN   tbl2 t2 ON t1.taxonomy_id = t2.id;
```

Barring that (if you cannot convert the column for some reason), a functional index would help:

```
CREATE INDEX tbl2_id_idx ON tbl2 (cast(id AS int));

SELECT *
FROM   tbl1 t1
JOIN   tbl2 t2 ON t1.taxonomy_id = t2.id::int;
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's a one-time task, I think you can do something like

```
...
from
 first_table join second_table
  on first_table.taxonomy_id = cast(second_table.id as int8)
...
```

However, this may not use the index on second_table.id if it exists, so performance will suffer. In the long run you will be better off converting the id column in second_table to the proper int data type.

Disclaimer: I don't have a Postgres installation handy to verify the example.

Comment: Change the *"this may not use the index"* to *"this **will** not use the index"*

Comment: ... or you may set up an index on `second_table.id::integer` as well

Comment: This may not work *at all*. I provided an explanation in my answer.

Comment: I don't know Postgres well enough, so you're probably right. Some other databases, DB2 for example, *may* still use an index in such a situation.

Comment: @mustaccio Handy PostgreSQL installation: http://sqlfiddle.com/