# Optimizing a simple query joining two big tables

Tags: postgresql, performance, index-tuning, postgresql-9.6, query-performance

I don't understand why the following query is so slow (with Postgresql 9.6):

```
SELECT s.pkid AS pkid_site , s.geom AS geom_site , z.pkid AS pkidEmprise, z.geom AS geom_emprise, z.précision_contour
FROM traitements.sites_candidats AS s
JOIN traitements.zones_sites AS z
    ON z.pkid_site = s.pkid
WHERE s.statut = 'selected'
AND z.statut = 'selected';
```

The structure of the tables is the following:

```
CREATE TABLE traitements.sites_candidats (
    pkid serial PRIMARY KEY,
    statut varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
    geom geometry(Point, 2154)
); 
CREATE INDEX ON traitements.sites_candidats (statut);

CREATE TABLE traitements.zones_sites (
    pkid serial PRIMARY KEY,
    pkid_site integer NOT NULL,
    geom geometry(MultiPolygon,2154),
    statut varchar(100)
);

CREATE INDEX zones_sites_idx_pkid_site  ON traitements.zones_sites (pkid_site);
CREATE INDEX zones_sites_idx_statut ON traitements.zones_sites (statut) ;
ALTER TABLE  traitements.zones_sites
    ADD CONSTRAINT zones_sites_references_sites_candidats FOREIGN KEY (pkid_site) REFERENCES traitements.sites_candidats(pkid) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

(I deleted a couple of columns that are not involved in the query in order to improve readability).

The result of `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`:

```
Hash Join  (cost=17709.29..152088.29 rows=147368 width=887) (actual time=137.074..879.884 rows=210708 loops=1)
  Hash Cond: (z.pkid_site = s.pkid)
  ->  Seq Scan on zones_sites z  (cost=0.00..85198.14 rows=210717 width=855) (actual time=0.140..384.964 rows=210708 loops=1)
        Filter: ((statut)::text = 'selected'::text)
        Rows Removed by Filter: 23
  ->  Hash  (cost=13433.16..13433.16 rows=210490 width=36) (actual time=136.772..136.772 rows=210708 loops=1)
        Buckets: 65536  Batches: 8  Memory Usage: 2191kB
        ->  Seq Scan on sites_candidats s  (cost=0.00..13433.16 rows=210490 width=36) (actual time=3.085..87.774 rows=210708 loops=1)
              Filter: ((statut)::text = 'selected'::text)
              Rows Removed by Filter: 90265
Planning time: 0.386 ms
Execution time: 888.436 ms
```

It's obviously the `JOIN .. ON` that consumes time because it does a hash.

Table `traitements.sites_candidats` has about 300k rows (210k of them with `statut='selected'`) and `traitements.zones_sites` about 210k rows (nearly 99% of have statut='selected'). The query takes more than 4 minutes.

Comment: The query takes less than a second to run (888 milliseconds) - if you are seeing "4 mintues" somewhere the difference is due to the way the rows are transferred and displayed in whatever application you use.

Comment: So do you have your answer?

Answer (score 4):

Composite indices including `statut` *might* help.
Since only rows with `statut = 'selected'` are of interest, **[partial indexes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-partial.html)** might help some more:

```
-- CREATE INDEX ON traitements.zones_sites (pkid_site)
-- WHERE statut = 'selected';  -- not useful for you!

CREATE INDEX ON traitements.sites_candidats (pkid)
WHERE statut = 'selected';     -- probably also not useful, yet
```

Smaller indices, less write load and fragmentation.

**However**, since most rows in `zones_sites` have `statut = 'selected'`, and since you fetch several columns from that table, and (almost) all rows, Postgres will stick to a sequential scan as fastest option and the only index that can help is the one on `sites_candidats` - where also ~ 70 % of all rows qualify. So a bitmap index scan using the above index would most likely still be more expensive than another sequential scan on `zones_sites`.

The remaining option to improve performance is an **index-only scan**. Consider appending the only other column of interest from `sites_candidats` to the index:

```
CREATE INDEX ON traitements.sites_candidats (pkid, geom)
WHERE statut = 'selected';
```

Only useful if [preconditions for index-only scans](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Index-only_scans) are met, and 
it becomes more attractive if the table is big and the appended column is small. Related:

- [Does PostgreSQL use an index-only scan in this JOIN?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/190156/does-postgresql-use-an-index-only-scan-in-this-join/190158#190158)

More on index-only scans in my answer to your last question:

- [Optimizing query with type casting](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/208699/optimizing-query-with-type-casting/208811#208811)

**Don't expect much**, retrieving `210708` rows (according to your `EXPLAIN` output) will still take some time. If you don't actually need all of them, consider `LIMIT` (combined with `ORDER BY`) or additional predicates to fetch fewer rows and make it much faster.

**Asides:**

I would not use accented letters in identifiers (like: `précision_contour`). While that works, it introduces potential encoding problems.

Why different data types for `statut`? `varchar(255)`, `varchar(100)`. Seems like those should be the same. If only a handful of states are possible, make that an [`enum`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-enum.html) or a tiny FK column pointing to a `statut` table - to make everything smaller and faster, yet. And less error-prone.

You had Postgres 9.5 in your last question yesterday, but Postgres 9.6 today. Did you just upgrade? If so, did you run `ANALYZE` after the upgrade? Table statistics are not carried over. Related:

- [Optimizing slow performance of simple SELECT query](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/187923/optimizing-slow-performance-of-simple-select-query/187981#187981)

Answer (score 0):

*<sub>[Community wiki answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki):</sub>*

I think you need to create composite indices on both tables: `(statut, pkid_site)` and `(statut, pkid)` on `zones_sites` and `sites_candidats` respectively.

Alternatively, it might be better indexing on `(pkid_site, statut)`, considering the foreign key between the two tables. That said, we have an inner join, not left/outer, so constant filtering first may be safer. Foreign key first could cause a scan of the whole index, while constant first scans only part of it.

After the indexing change, the existing indices on the `statut` field in both tables may be removed.